# Let $≺$ be a relation on a set $P$, reflexive and transitive. Def. $∼$ on $P$ by $p ∼ q \iff p ≺ q ∧ q ≺ p$. Show $∼$ is an equiv. relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, equivalence-relations

Can I get some help on this one? Any solutions?

---

Let $≺$ be a relation on a set $P$ that is reflexive and transitive.
Define the relation $∼$ on $P$ by

$p ∼ q$ iff $p ≺ q ∧ q ≺ p$.

(a) Show $∼$ is an equivalence relation.

(b) Given any $p ∈ P$, let $[p]$ denote the $∼$-equivalence class of $p$.
Define $(P/∼, ⪯)$ to comprise the set $P/∼$ of $∼$-equivalence
classes on which $x ⪯ y$ iff $∃p, q. (x = [p]) ∧ (y = [q]) ∧ p ≺ q$.

Show $(P/∼, ⪯)$ is a partial order.

Ok, this is what I got:

An equivalence relation is:

Reflexive:$p~p → p≺p ∧ q≺q$

Which is true since the relation $≺$ is reflexive.

Symmetric:if $p~q$ then $q~p → p≺q ∧  q≺p$ then $q≺p ∧ p≺q$
Which must be true since the logical operator “and” do not stipulate that the statements are fixed to either side of the operator.

Transitive:if $p~q$ and $q~u$ then $p~u → p≺q ∧ q≺p$ and $q≺u ∧ u≺q$ then $p≺u ∧ u≺p$
Which is true since the relation $≺$ is transitive.

Is this on the right track.
Have no clue what to do in part b).

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Your p p, q p,  p q notation is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

[p] <= [p] because p <= p

If x <= y, y <= x, then exists p,q,r,s with
x = [p], y = [q], y = [r], x = [s], p <= q, r <= s, p ~ s, q ~ r.
Show p <= r, r <= p;  x = [p] = [r] = y.

If x <= y, y <= z, then exists p,q,r,s with
x = [p], y = [q], y = [r], z = [s], p <= q, r <= s, q ~ r.
Show p <= s;  x = [p] <= [s] = z.